# Proof that if $x$ minimises $\left \| Ax-b \right \|^{2}_2 +\mu\left \| x \right \|^{2}_2$ then it solves regularised normal equations

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm looking for a proof that if $x$ minimises $\left \| Ax-b \right \|^{2}_2 +\mu\left \| x \right \|^{2}_2$ then it solves $(A^{T}A+\mu I)x=A^{T}b$

Comment: Isn't this just taking the gradient of $\|Ax-b\|_2^2+\mu\|x\|_2^2$ and equating it to zero?

Comment: @Batominovski I'm not sure? It could be but I'm not sure how to go about that?